# Sky-Watcher Skymax-127 (AZ) 127mm (5") f/1500 SynScan GO-TO Maksutov-Cassegrain Telescope

Tags: astronomy, telescopes

I have not purchased the above item yet but was wondering whether or not I should? Can I hook this scope up to a monitor or laptop so I can see what my scope is seeing? Is this scope is any good at viewing planets etc., Mars and Saturn in particular? Will it give clear views of nebulae etc.?

Thanks for your responses.

Answer (score 2):

Optically and mechanically, this telescope's optical tube is identical to the Orion Apex and StarMax 127mm Maksutov-Cassegrain, but on a different GoTo mount.  While the SkyWatcher brand may not be familiar in the United States, it is widely known in the rest of the world as the house brand of Synta, the largest telescope manufacturer in the world.

A medium sized Maksutov-Cassegrain like this makes an excellent telescope for lunar and planetary observing.  It is less suitable for deep sky observing because of its narrow field of view.

Just about any telescope can be hooked up to a video camera or webcam.  This is useful for imaging the Moon and planets, but is too much trouble for general observing. Most of us just prefer to look directly through the eyepiece, rather than watch on a monitor.